# A question on mutual quantum information

Tags: quantum-information

As I have seen, the usual definition of mutual quantum information concerns with bipartite systems, which makes perfect sense to me. However, I was wondering if it makes any  sense to speak about the mutual information of a pair of states both living in the same (single partie) quantum system.

Comment: Can you give a more specific s set up as an example?

Comment: I'm not sure how this would make sense. At the end of the day the mutual information is about correlations between pairs of measurement results. If you only have one system, with no bipartite structure, you cannot have different measurement results and thus correlations to study

Comment: @glS You could look at commuting measurements rather than those which tensorize as $A\otimes I$ vs. $I\otimes B$.

Comment: @shaihorowitz I was wondering on the meaning of prhases like this: the state A of a quantum system has at least much information as the state B'. This seems to be relate to the mutual information between A and B...My confusión is, what is the meaning of a prhase like this if one start with a pair of states A and B both living in the same quantum system.

Comment: The idea there are the rules are deterministic. From a classical perspective this is equivalent to the fact that if you knew every particles velocities and positions and masses at any given time then you can predict the position at any other time.